# Let $T$ be a bounded linear operator on a Hilbert space. If $T$ is normal, how do I prove that null space of $T$ equals the null space of $T^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I can prove that $N(T)=N(T^*).$ How do I proceed from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you get from $N(T)=N(T^*)$ is that 
$$
R(T)=N(T^*)^\perp=N(T)^\perp.
$$
So, if $T^2x=0$, you have that $Tx\in N(T)\cap R(T)=\{0\}$. Thus $Tx=0$.

Answer (score 1):

From what you know
\begin{align}
       T^2x & = 0 \iff T^*Tx = 0 \\
            & \implies \langle T^*Tx,x\rangle = 0 \\
            & \implies \langle Tx,Tx\rangle =0 \\
            & \implies Tx = 0
\end{align}
The opposite implication that $Tx=0 \implies T^2x=0$ is clear.